# ExpoMetroConfig.loadAsync is not a function when i run "npx expo start"

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, npx

I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: ExpoMetroConfig.loadAsync is not a function
    at runMetroDevServerAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/src/MetroDevServer.ts:86:45)
    at startDevServerAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/start/startDevServerAsync.ts:75:77)
    at startAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/start/startAsync.ts:84:41)".
```

And I'm using `npx` but it's like I'm using `local-cli`, I don't know why.

I've already used `npx expo-doctor` but it continues to show that there is an error with the packages, and `npx expo-doctor --fix-dependencies` results in  `--fix-dependencies does not exist`
[image][image]

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
npm install @expo/config@8.1.1
npm install @expo/metro-config@0.10.0
```

Worked for me, found here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26593#issuecomment-1905239481

Comment: It looks like the same link where I found the solution, luckily it's already solved, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26593#issuecomment-1906107694

I followed these steps and everything is working now, (I didn't uninstall the @expo/metro-config package and I didn't do anything with metro.conf.js)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issues when I upgraded my expo using : `expo upgrade` or upgrading a bare react-native-project. I had to clear Metro Bundler cache using Watchman.

Steps:

1. Install Watchman

2: Then run:

`watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean --force && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`

on root folder of your project.